# Read from requests.get

Tags: python

i have this request but its with a strange behaviour and im having dificulties get the values a need.

heres an example:

```
response = requests.get('https://api-prd.dev/analytics/api/properties?filter[a.id]=' + aid, headers=headers)
request = response.json()
print(":0:->>>> ", request['data'][0])
```

the prints are like this:

```
:0:->>>>  {'type': 'id-snapshot-property', 'id': 'adblue_level_percentage', 'attributes': {'updateDate': '2022-10-07T13:39:32Z', 'value': '0'}}
```

How do i get the value 0 in adblue_level_percentage

response: `request['data'][0]['attributes']['value']`

Comment: `123` is ascii for `{`, `34` is ascii for `"` - you're printing the bytes in the actual response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just use `Response.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.json()
[{'repository': {'open_issues': 0, 'url': 'https://github.com/...'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
response = requests.get('https://api-prd.dev/analytics/api/properties?filter[a.id]=' + aid, headers=headers)

request = json.loads(response)
```

now you have dict object and fetch value by calling dict key

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.get('https://api-prd.dev/analytics/api/properties?filter[a.id]=' + aid, headers=headers)

data = response.json()
```

This should also work. It also delivers a dictionary which you can access via its keys.